# Using Wireshark in ubuntu for analyzing android requests?

Tags: android, wireshark

I am using ubuntu 10.04 LTS and have a android ICS device.

I created a wifi-hotspot in my android device. I am connecting the my ubuntu via the wifi-hotspot created above. I stared capturing the packets from wireshark in my pc.

I am unable to see the traffic generated from the device, rather I can see only the traffic from the pc.

Am I missing something or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't seeing the traffic from the phone because your computer is only receiving and sending packets intended for the computer.

Maybe this will help? http://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#promiscsniff

It is possible that your wireless interface device either isn't in promiscuous mode or doesn't support it.

Comment: Your answer acted as an eye opener to me. Tethering creates some internal private IP within android which makes it impossible to monitor the WIFI traffic in the device. That is why I was seeing only the traffic from my PC alone. This post explains more about the promiscuous mode in android, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11703/does-android-tethering-support-promiscuous-mode.

Comment: I should have tried the other way around ie creating hotspot in ubuntu and accessing the hotspot from the mobile.

Comment: Yes, that probably would have been the way to do it. There is the alternative of cache poisoning the phone (not sure if that works on Android phones) to perform a sort of man in the middle attack.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you, i would scan for all hosts alive in the subnet.Sure android device acts as a hotspot using NAT or something, i'm sure.But the catch is it's moreover a server to which only your pc or whatever might be connected, i guess it would be your lapton. But android itself uses the external ip like service bsnl or something. So it's not at all a client connected to a router or something.

Still if you run an nmap scan you would surely see the default gateway ip, which is of the hotspot.

So, it's enough said right.